# Spark connection to slave on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

So I have my master node on my Mac and I can check on the webserver my master url as `spark://private_ip_address:7077`. Then I try to connect a slave node on a remote server.

So I run `start-slaves.sh` from the master and it creates a log on the remote server. So I assume that the ssh connection is ok. However the connection with the master is not possible as shown by the log content.

```
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO ResourceUtils: ==============================================================
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO WorkerWebUI: Bound WorkerWebUI to 127.0.0.0, and started at http://127.0.0.0:8081
21/01/12 13:06:36 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:06:48 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 1)
21/01/12 13:06:48 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:00 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 2)
21/01/12 13:07:00 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:12 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 3)
21/01/12 13:07:12 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:24 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 4)
21/01/12 13:07:24 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:36 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 5)
21/01/12 13:07:36 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:07:48 INFO Worker: Retrying connection to master (attempt # 6)
21/01/12 13:07:48 INFO Worker: Connecting to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077...
21/01/12 13:08:36 ERROR RpcOutboxMessage: Ask terminated before connecting successfully
21/01/12 13:08:36 WARN NettyRpcEnv: Ignored failure: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /master_node_private_ip_address:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
21/01/12 13:08:36 WARN Worker: Failed to connect to master master_node_private_ip_address:7077
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult: 
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:302)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$$anon$1.run(Worker.scala:277)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connecting to /master_node_private_ip_address:7077 timed out (120000 ms)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:251)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:195)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:204)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:202)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:198)
    ... 4 more
```

I would be so grateful for some help to understand why this does not connect properly and show on the webserver the slave node.

Comment: You checked that master -> slave was possible, but did you check that it's possible to connect from slave -> master?

Comment: can you try to ssh into the slave, and then ssh back to the master?

Comment: @mck thanks, I tried to ping the public ip address and the private ip address but it does not work. Ping the dns worked. I don't really know where to look

Comment: test the ssh connection, not the ping.

Comment: @mck I did not know that it was possible to ssh back the local after sshed the remote server. I tried and it does not work. The public ssh key that I put in my local Mac is the root user key from the remote server. However I ssh the remote with a specific user name which is not root and which has no ssh key generated. So I though that ssh key may not apply system wide and tried to ssh back to the local Mac after doing a `sudo su root`. But it still does not work. Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, normally that's not possible, and I guess that's why your slaves can't find their master... I guess you'll need to allow the slaves to ssh into your master so that they can talk

Comment: super user might be a better place to ask

Comment: @mck sorry could you specify what is not possible please? Thank you, I will post again on super user based and directly ask about my ssh issue

Comment: I mean sshing from remote to local is normally not possible, unless you allow and set up ssh properly on your local machine.